# Insert a GIF image into JFrame and make it visible and invisible on demand

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, imageicon

In my application I am extracting data from a project DB. When I do that I want to signal to user that data extraction is in progress. I want to achieve this by making my current frame `view.getFrame2()` invisible and making `view.getFrame3()` visible. Frame 3 will have GIF image with frame titled as "Extraction is in progress". I am able to achieve my target but I am not able to view the image in the frame. It's blank.

Below is the code snippet I am using; one class is used for view, another one for controller and yet another one for the model. I also have a main class to initialize all the M-V-C classes. I don't want to complicate the code by creating more classes.

### View

```
My View class:-
/** View**/
package mvc.views;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.*;

public class View {
 JFrame frame2, frame3;
  JPanel  panel3;
  Toolkit tk; 
  Image   icon;
  Color   background;
  public View() {
 /** processing image view **/

    frame3 =new JFrame();

    frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame3.setTitle( "Extraction in process...." );

      try {
            icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\pc033k\\Desktop\\gears_animated.gif").getImage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    panel3 = new JPanel();
    background = Color.white;
    panel3.setOpaque(true);
    frame3.setContentPane(panel3);;            
    frame3.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
    frame3.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame3.setVisible(false);
    /** End of processing image view **/ 
}
public void paint (Graphics g)
  {
    panel3.paint(g);

    panel3.setBackground(background);
    g.drawImage(icon,100,100,500,500,null);

    }
 } 
 /** End of View**/
```

### Controller

```
/** Start Controller**/
package mvc.controllers;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

import mvc.models.*;
import mvc.views.*;
public class Controller {
 public Model model;
 public View view;
 public ActionListener myButtonListener;
 //public MyDateListener listener;
 boolean status, process1;
 public String user, password, FN, LN, type;

 JTextField text1, text2;
 JCalendarCombo cal1, cal2;


 public Date date1, date2;

 public Controller(Model model, View view) {

    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
}

    public class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() == view.getGetcrmdataButton()){

                FN = view.getUserText1().getText();
                LN = view.getUserText2().getText();
                date1 = view.getCalendar2().getDate();
                date2 = view.getCalendar3().getDate();
                type = (String) view.getComb1().getSelectedItem();
                view.getFrame2().dispose();
                view.getFrame3().setVisible(true);
                view.getFrame3().repaint();



                try {
                     process1 = model.CRMDataExtract(FN, LN, date1, date2, type);

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(process1 == true){

                    view.getFrame3().setVisible(false);
                    view.getFrame2().setVisible(true);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) (e.getSource()),
                            "pealse Check the output file for the data");



                }
                else
                {
                    view.getFrame3().setVisible(false);
                    view.getFrame2().setVisible(true);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) (e.getSource()),
                            " No Records found or Data Extraction failed!!");
                }



            }


    }

}
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: BTW - *"Insert a GIF image into JFrame and make it visible and invisible on demand"*  the easiest way to do this is to display the image in a `JLabel`.  To make it invisible, set a new icon that it the same size as the original image, but entirely transparent (e.g. `new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPEE_INT_ARGB)`).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks for suggestion. I will try to implement in my future development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to achieve this by making my current frame view.getFrame2() invisible and make a view.getFrame3() visible.

Don't be hiding/showing different windows. Users don't like frames disappearing. Instead you can simply display a modal JDialog containing your image on top of your main frame.

Or another approach is to use a `GlassPane` that paints over top of your main frame. See [Disabled Glass Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) for an example of this approach. The existing example doesn't use an Icon, but you can easily change that.

Comment: Your JDialog idea is more suitable to me thank you. But my program is not moving further untill i press ok on dialog box. what i should do if my program should execute as it is while my dialog box appears as well?

Comment: @pardhu, you need to use a "non modal" JDialog. Read the API for more information. The constructors have a property you can set or you can set the property after the dialog has been created (but before you make it visible).

Comment: can i using "non modal" for JOptionPane? if so how?

Comment: By the way i tried setting non modal for JDialog Component. But its coming blank. I doubt this is happening because my control is busy in executing my model class. do we have a solution for this?

Comment: @pardhu, read the JOptionPane API. It show you the manual code needed to directly create the option pane and use it in a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a label for insert the image.
Also I think CardLayout more suitable to your work. Here is some sample code. Consider that the Sample is a JFrame. You will see the Panel changes as you press the "Next" button.

```
 public Sample() {

        p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new CardLayout());

        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/chrisbanks2/cold-fusion-hd/128/ace-of-spades-icon.png"))));

        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/chrisbanks2/cold-fusion-hd/128/ace-of-hearts-icon.png"))));

        p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p3.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/chrisbanks2/cold-fusion-hd/128/angrybirds-2-icon.png"))));

        p.add(p1, "0");
        p.add(p2, "1");
        p.add(p3, "2");

        b = new Button("Next");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rotator++;
                if (rotator == 3) {
                    rotator = 0;
                }
                CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) p.getLayout();
                layout.show(p, "" + rotator);
                System.out.println("Rotator " + rotator);

            }
        });

        add(p, "Center");
        add(b, "North");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Lalith, your suggestion is helpful for me for my future development of the tool i will keep your suggestion in mind ty :)