# Java Swing JButton Actionlistener to change another package

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I have a code and my problem is toggling visibility of `JPanel` with `JButton`. Here are my Packages - Classes:

start  - Main
panels - Panels
labels - Labels

I am creating the button in package `labels` class `Labels` with this

```
public static JButton ScriptDLBotton(JPanel navPanel) {
  JButton contactsButton = new JButton("Show");
  contactsButton.setVisible(true);
  contactsButton.setBounds(250,82,70, 20);
  navPanel.add(contactsButton); 
  return contactsButton;
}
```

I am calling it from `start.Main` with this

```
JButton ScriptDLbutton = Labels.ScriptDLBotton(AppsPanel)
```

And I want when I press the button it go to package `panels` class `Panels` and change

```
public static JPanel createAppDiscriptionPanel(JFrame frame) {
  JPanel navDiscPanel = new JPanel ();
  navDiscPanel.setVisible(false);
  navDiscPanel.setBounds(350,100,640, 380);
  navDiscPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  navDiscPanel.setLayout(null);
  frame.add(navDiscPanel);
  return navDiscPanel;}
```

from visible `false` to `true`. Thx in advance for any help.

Comment: good one, now please to post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: read Oracle tutorial - How to use CardLayout

Comment: Link to what mKorbel said [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: How does it have anything to do with layout ?

Comment: Correct Layout can save you :). Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580177/inset-a-gif-image-in-a-jframe-make-it-visible-and-invisible-whenever-i-want/27580708#27580708